# Use Case diagram for board game

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm creating a use case diagram for a checkers game that I programmed. How in-depth are you really supposed to go when making these? I read that they are supposed to be simple, but that is kind of vague. Do I need to create more arrows, for example between "move regular" (which means move a regular piece, as oppose to a king) and "jump"? Or is it fine not having a connection there? I just don't want to make too many arrows because it will begin to look pretty messy. Any input will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) ..UML..diagram..how in-depth are you..supposed to..do I need..more arrows..don't want..it..look..messy..?

How in-depth and how simple depends on many factors, basically on an answer to *"why you need it"* and *"who will read it"*.

Actually the set of questions and guides and other practices that can help you decide can be quite long. Especially useful one is listed in the chapter [Agine Modeling: Agile/Lean Documentation: Strategies for Agile Software Development](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/agileDocumentation.htm) in Scott W. Ambler's online book.

One thing that you should get absolutely clear is what kinds of UML diagrams you need/want

### 2) UML..use case diagram..more arrows..or..no..connection..too many arrows..?

The arrows in use case diagrams are not an arbitrary connection lines but instead they have precise meaning, especially the `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>` relationship, see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-reference.html for their definition and examples

[image]

Besides being graphical bubbles the use case represent how an [actor](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html) interacts with the System Under Design. Content of the bubbles is then described in more/less formalized text form, see [Wikipedia: Use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) and especially [Alistair Cockburn's use case pages](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Use+cases%2c+ten+years+later) as he basically defined meaning of the term (later adopted by UML) his opinion matters.

### 3) I'm creating a..UML..diagram for a checkers game that I programmed..

In your case the `King Piece` bubble does not seem to be included-in or extending the `Start Game` bubble initiated by the `Player` and I don't see what sequence of steps might be hidden inside its textual representation (or in your code).

The things you began to draw look much more like [UML Activity Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html), an example

[image]

and some explaining links:

- overview [Debenedetti Emanuele, Activity diagrams in UML 2.0](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/ReggioG/ISII04WWW/ActivityDiagrams.ppt)
- background by Conrad Bock (one of UML authors), UML 2 Activity and Action Models, The Journal of Object Technology

  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_07/column3/index.html)
  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 2: Actions](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_09/column4/index.html)
  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 3: Control Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_11/column1/index.html)
  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 4: Object Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/index.html)
  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 5: Partitions](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_07/column4/index.html)
  - [UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 6: Structured Activities](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_05/column4/index.html)
- tool manuals

  - [PaceStar UML Diagrammer](http://www.pacestar.com/uml/), UML Diagramming Guide - http://www.pacestar.com/uml/udg60.pdf
  - [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html), Using UML Part Two – Behavioral Modeling Diagram - http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/whitepapers/UML_Tutorial_Part_2_Introduction.pdf
  - [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare), UML Activity Diagrams - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409360.aspx

Comment: Yes, it really looks like there is only one use case: play checkers.  One use case can of course be fully modeled by one activity diagram.

Answer (score 2):

There are much less use cases here. Pls refer to the following diagram drawn by myself:
[image]

The other requirements can be written in use case specification, specially the business rules.

Use case name: Move piece

Actors: Player (Primary)

Pre-conditions: ******

Post-conditions: ******

Stakeholders and Interests: ******

Basic Path:

1. Player selects one piece and the destination square, and submit a move request.
2. System validates destination square.
3. System moves the piece and calculates the moving.
4. System displays the moving result.

Exception Path:

2a. destination square is not valid:

2a1. System ****

---

Business Rule:

2. valid destination square : ……
3. calculating rule, such as king piece, win game……